# Can I save the classes of a file to a list?

Tags: python

Let's say I have two files.
First one is `a.py`, where I define many classes:

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    pass

class C:
    pass

...
```

In the second file `b.py`, I hope to access the classes of `a.py` in a list. How can I do that?

```
# class_list is the classes of a.py
for class_def in class_list:
    do_something(class_def)
```

Comment: One way would be `dir(a)`, but you'd need to check if they are classes or other things.

Comment: @Peter that also may leak all the classes that `a.py` happens to import.

Comment: I tried to do dir(a), but how? I cannot `import a`. I can only `from a import *`.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to iterate over the module attributes and take those which are classes, like mentioned in the comments. But that makes it easy to leak the classes that are imported by `a.py` and those which you don't intend to export to `b.py`.

I'd make it explicit, for example, in `a.py`:

```
exported = [A, B, C]
```

and in `b.py`:

```
for cls in a.exported:
    do_something(cls)
```

Alternatively, you can make it in a more fancy way using decorators, in `a.py`:

```
exported = []

def export(cls):
     exported.append(cls)
     return cls

@export
class A:
    pass

...
```

And `b.py` remains the same.

Comment: Could you also provide the code to iterate the module attributes? Thank you.

Comment: @AugustinPan it makes sense only if you can `import a`, but you mentioned that you can only `from a import ...` (why is that, btw?)